# Sigma baryons have strangeness

Tags: nuclear-physics, standard-model, quarks, baryons

An exercise I am trying to solve is as follows:
$Σ$ baryons have a charge of either ${-1,0,+1}$. Show that their strangeness is $S=-1$.

I thought one can argue that since they are baryon, they'll be made up of 3 quarks. Also, if we consider $Σ^+$ for example, one could argue that for it to have a charge of $+1$ it has to be made up of $(uus)$. But if it was made up of let's say $(uub)$, then the charge would still be $+1$. Or even $(ccb)$.
So my question is, how is it possible to specify that it has a strange quark.

Comment: @ George, Baryon may have charge +2 as well. Example $\Delta^{++}$.

Comment: Indeed, however for that question we only need to look at a charge of either ${+,-},0$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have missed some details in the text of your exercise. In fact, you are probably only referring to the isospin triplet $\Sigma^+, \Sigma^-,\Sigma^0$, which are composed by two up/downs and one strange quark. As you say, there are many other $\Sigma$ baryons that contain a charm, a bottom or a top quark instead of the strange. All of these have obviously $S=0$, but some of them can have charge of $0$ or $\pm 1$.

If $S=-1$ and B is the baryonic number, you have for the hypercharge

$$Y=S+B=-1+1=0$$

Therefore the charge is

$$Q=I_3 +\frac{Y}{2}=I_3$$

Which can be either $0$ or $\pm 1$, since the $\Sigma^+, \Sigma^-,\Sigma^0$ form an isospin triplet.

Comment: Your answer has a flaw, Actual equation for strong hypercharge  is $Y =B+S+T+B'$ (B' for beauty). Therefore their no a prori way to set $T=B=B'=0$. $Y$ can also be zero for $S=B'=T=0$. And the answer just give mathematical justification rather than the experimental facts.

Comment: As I said, I showed how you get to this result for the triplet $\Sigma^+ \Sigma^- \Sigma^0$, therefore I set $T=C=B'=0$. As I pointed out you can have other combinations that include the $c$, $b$, $t$ quarks and give the same result for the charge, so there was an ambiguity in the way the exercise was stated. What you say about the experimental evidence is correct, but I don't think that this is what the original question is about. Let's see what he says!

Comment: Firstly, thank you both for your answers. Thing is, I didn't miss any detail, as the text of the exercise is literally one line, and it doesn't say that they build an isospin triplet. If it did, then surely we could say that it's made up of some combination of up and down quarks. But as it only gives us the charge of them without any prior knowledge, I don't see how we can exclude the charm, top and bottom quarks. Unless I misunderstood some part of your reasoning.

Comment: Then I really don't know how to solve the ambiguity with the data you possess. Could it be that you discussed in class a model with only the $u$, $d$ and $s$ quarks? In this case you could assume that by $\Sigma$ the exercise actually means only the triplet $(\Sigma^+, \Sigma^-, \Sigma^0)$.

Comment: Which text you are using?

Comment: Hi again! I got some more information and I realized that usually when the people in the field talk about the $\Sigma$ baryons refer specifically to the isospin triplet containing the $s$ quark. The others are more exotic particles and are called $\Sigma_c$ (Sigma charm) etc.. So I think it is possible that your exercise only wants you to consider those ones. In any case, you should check it with your teacher if you are following a course.

Comment: @mas The text is not in English and the translation of it is what I wrote.

Comment: @DelCrosB, I agree with you. Under $SU(3)_{f}$ they comes as an octet, with $T_{3}=+1,0,-1$.

Comment: @ DelCrosB So if I understand correctly what you are saying, $Σ$ baryons containing more exotic quarks have all indices of said quarks?

Comment: Yes, this the usual notation. Whether this is relevant or not depends on the the notation of your book and on the context. Does your book discuss the $SU(3)$ flavour symmetry? Does it talk at all about the heavier quarks and the hadrons that they can form?

Comment: We don't really use a book for the course. It is based on the lectures of the professors instead. Anyway, I think your explanation with the $Σ$ baryon notation is the most plausible. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, I hope that this was the issue in the end! You could probably ask your professor in any case. If you find that it is correct, please consider upvoting or accepting my answer (I'm not sure why it currently has a downvote).

Answer (score 1):

Your question has a definite point.

The Sigma baryons are a family of subatomic hadron particles which have a +2, +1 or −1 elementary charge or are neutral. They are baryons containing three quarks:

**two up and/or down quarks, and one third quark, if that is strange quark then corresponding particle are $\Sigma^{+}, \Sigma^{0}, \Sigma^{-}$.**

Now if the third quark is a **charm**, **beauty** or **truth**  then corresponding sigma baryons are  $\Sigma^{++}_{c}, \Sigma^{+}_{c}, \Sigma^{0}_{c}$ and $\Sigma^{+}_{b}, \Sigma^{0}_{b}, \Sigma^{-}_{b}$ and $\Sigma^{++}_{t}, \Sigma^{+}_{t}, \Sigma^{0}_{t}$ respectively.

Now lets come to your question: how one can identify the $\Sigma^{+}$ which contain strange quark rather than **b** or **t** quark.To get the answer lets have a look on the life time of these baryons:
[image]
[the table has been taken from wikipedia]
Have a look on the mass and mean life time of sigma's. The life time of charm and botttom sigma's are $~10^{10}$ times shorter than that of strange sigmas. And they are roughly two times heavier than $\Sigma_{s}^{+,0,-}$.

Another fact is decay channel for each of sigma baryons are different depending on their quark compositions.

**So one can identify the quark content $\Sigma$ baryon considering the life time and mass of the particles and of course their possible decay channel.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this exercise is taken from an old exam and the decay times were not given. And you also seem to assume, that the $Σ$ baryons of said charge, are made up of a combination of up and down quarks. If we use both those facts, then yes, your answer is obviously correct using their half-lives. But I don't understand how you reason, that they must be made up of up and down quarks. Couldn't the $Σ^+$ be $(ccb)$ for all we know? (Without looking at the table of course.)

Comment: @ George, Answer of your question goes as follows: Based on standard model ($SU(3)$ symmetry in particular), nothing prohibit to have state like $(ccb)$. But point is we did not observed it yet. Which does not even mean that the particle dont exists. Exotic hadrons like pentaquarks ($qqqq\bar{q}$) was predicted by Gelmann at sixties. Which just observed recently. In that sense, your question seems still open.